# Abelian subgroup of a profinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-commutative profinite group, and $H \subset G$ an abelian subgroup.

Is it true that $H$ have not finite index in $G$?

Comment: Take $H$ be an abelian profinite group, $K$ a finite non-commutative group, and $G=H\times K$?

Comment: You are right. However, May this properties holds for $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$?